# JS - Stripping tags while preserving line breaks works with DOM object, but not html in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plaintext

I'm trying to create a function in javascript (or jQuery) that will take a **variable** filled with html and output a plain text version. The function needs to strip the html tags and insert line breaks at the end of heading and paragraph tags.

I've been going round in circles for ages with this. There are lots of examples of how to take a DOM object, e.g. `document.body.innerHTML` and remove the tags. However, I'm using a **variable** filled with html and the results are not the same.

This is the supposed duplicate solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8JSZX/. However, create an html variable and use that and you get: http://jsfiddle.net/JjXXY/ - which does not preserve the line breaks.

The `html` variable would be something like:

```
var html = '<h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p><p>This is another paragraph</p>'
```

If there is a better solution to this I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Argh! This isn't a duplicate! If you read the question, I was asking how to use a variable and not a DOM object. The duplicate solution does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Gave it a shot:

```
var html_string = '<h1>Test</h1><p>A paragraph with a <a href="link">link</a></p>';
var regex = /<(\/?)[a-zA-Z0-9][^>]*>/g;
var stripped = html_string.replace(regex, '');
$("#result").html(stripped);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6q2j/5/